# Powershell long network copy & semaphore timeout

Tags: powershell, timeout, semaphore

Does Powershell (5.0) initialize network file transfers before they start?

Picture it, a script that copies TBs of files from a Server 2008 R2 SMB share, it takes days and days over a slowish link.

```
$remoteFiles = get-childitems -File -Recurse M:\Storage

foreach($remoteFile in $remoteFiles)
{
copy-item $remoteFile -Destination e:\
}
```

Sometime in day 2 it will start to throw Semaphore Timeout errors for the copy-item task.

But this will run perfectly fine for the entire multi day transfer...

```
$remoteFiles = get-childitems -File -Recurse M:\Storage

While($remoteFiles)
{
     foreach($remoteFile in $remoteFiles[0..1])
     {
         copy-item $remoteFile -Destination e:\
         #...Some funtion to remove this $remoteFile from $remoteFiles... you get the idea
     }
}
```

So I'm wondering what Powershell is doing with this loop.  It seams like it's reading ahead and starting the network session for every file, which would be fine for small jobs, but timesout for something that will take days to complete.

Comment: Your loop doesn't make any sense; it's an infinite loop if you're not removing entries from the `$remoteFiles` collection.  This sounds like an XY problem; I suggest using robocopy or another purpose-built tool for file transfers.

Comment: Sure sure, yes, the while loop needs to include a line to update $remoteFiles.  That's not really the question though...

Comment: I think you may want to look at [Using Windows PowerShell to Create BITS Transfer Jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bits/using-windows-powershell-to-create-bits-transfer-jobs). A nivce explanation can be found [here](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2017/08/03/leverage-bits-for-file-transfers-with-powershell.aspx)

Comment: Ya, BITS is an option, though it lacks a -literalpath switch, so you can't always use it in place of copy-item.